# How to build a preference record associated with a user in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In Ruby on Rails, when a new `user` is created I want to automatically create an associated `preference` record to that user.

This is my controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      @user.build_preference 
      redirect_to root_path, :notice => "User created."
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

end
```

However, for some reason I can't get this to work. The user gets saved successfully but when I check the database there is no related `preference` record.

What am I missing here?

Is it better to create the associated record from within the model using `:before_create` or something?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It might help to see your `User#build_preference` method, because my first guess is that the problem is in there.

Comment: What does build_preference do, and is this preference part of the User model?

Comment: Actually, my intention was to use Rails' built in [`build_association`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Reflection/AssociationReflection/build_association) method here. Or is that not a good fit here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `save`:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    pr = @user.build_preference
    pr.save!
    redirect_to root_path, :notice => "User created."
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but I get an error `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in UsersController#create` when I try to create a new record that way.

Comment: could you paste full error?? I think its because you have some validations on `preference`

Comment: Ah yes, I had to use `pr.save!(:validate => false)` to make it work. Thanks!

Comment: But its not a good way to do. You need to put valid values when you create object. So get required values for `preference` to create it then use `@user.build_preference(params[:user][:preference])`. Because it throw error when u try to access `user.preference`

Comment: OK, you were right. In fact I had to add a couple of `:allow_blank => true` options to the validations in my `Preference` model and now everything works. Thanks for your help.